# Complex increasing number of elements in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create a XSD schema rule that allows the following:

```
<Polynom>
  <Order>
    <Coefficients>
      <Coefficient>0</Coefficient>
    </Coefficients>
    <Coefficients>
      <Coefficient>1</Coefficient>
      <Coefficient>0</Coefficient>
    </Coefficients>
    <Coefficients>
      <Coefficient>3</Coefficient>
      <Coefficient>2</Coefficient>
      <Coefficient>1</Coefficient>
    </Coefficients>
  </Order>
</Polynom>
```

Now if it was only this it would be simple, however it should be possible to vary the amount of `Coefficients`. So if I add another one, that one MUST have four `Coefficient`

I'm not even sure this is possible with xsd?

**Update:**
Just to clarify, the first `Coefficients` must have one and exactly one `Coefficient`, then n-th `Coefficients` in a set of n `Coefficents` must have n `Coefficient`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible mate from standard occurrence restriction.

Comment: It is not possible with occurrence restrictions, but it is with `xs:assert` in XSD 1.1 as [described below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33535731/290085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint can be expressed in XSD 1.1 using `xs:assert`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="Polynom">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Order">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Coefficients" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Coefficient" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                                type="xs:integer"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="every $c in Coefficients satisfies
                             count($c/Coefficient) = count($c/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Your constraint cannot be expressed in XSD 1.0.